# I want to update /refresh a ListView when a List item is deleted

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I want to refresh /update ListView data when an ImageView is click in the ListView item row.

This is my Adapter class

```
public class ListImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private List<EntityObject> dataStorage;

private Context context;

public ListImageAdapter(Context context, List<EntityObject> customizedListView) {
    this.layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
    this.dataStorage = customizedListView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dataStorage.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dataStorage.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if(convertView == null){
        listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_images, parent, false);

        listViewHolder.downloadedImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.displayed_image);
        listViewHolder.deleteIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_image);
        listViewHolder.imageFilename = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.downloaded_filename);
        convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
    }else{
        listViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    listViewHolder.imageFilename.setText(dataStorage.get(position).getName());
    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Helper.PATH_TO_EXTERNAL_STORAGE + File.separator + dataStorage.get(position).getImage()));
    Glide.with(context).load(imageUri).override(90, 90).centerCrop().into(listViewHolder.downloadedImage);

    listViewHolder.deleteIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String deleteImageName = listViewHolder.imageFilename.getText().toString();
            String deletePath = Helper.PATH_TO_EXTERNAL_STORAGE + File.separator + deleteImageName;
            File deleteFile = new File(deletePath);
            if(deleteFile.exists()){
                deleteFile.delete();
                Toast.makeText(context, "The image has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
public void refreshDataStorage(List<EntityObject> listObject) {
    this.dataStorage = listObject;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

static class ViewHolder{

    ImageView downloadedImage;

    ImageView deleteIcon;

    TextView imageFilename;
}
```

I have tried to call this method in the Activity class but it did not update the ListView data after deletion

```
public void refreshDataStorage(List<EntityObject> listObject) {
this.dataStorage = listObject;
this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This method is called in onCreate() method of the host Activity class

```
        /// add an adapter for the listView
        workingDataSource = returnDataSource(mainStorageDirectory);
        listImageAdapter = new ListImageAdapter(ListImagesActivity.this, workingDataSource);
        listAllImages.setAdapter(listImageAdapter);

        listImageAdapter.refreshDataStorage(workingDataSource);
```

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: I don't think you need to call refreshdatastorage in your adapter.

Comment: where did you use the method refreshDataStorage?

Comment: In the Activity class. See update

Comment: You delete the file, however, `listObject` not updated (its item not removed). So, pls call something like `listObject.remove(...); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @BNK, thanks. I get it working with your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment, you have deleted the file, however, the `listObject` not updated (its item not removed). So, please call something like the following

```
listObject.remove(...); 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

Pls change to

```
public void refreshDataStorage(List<EntityObject> listObject) {
    this.dataStorage.clear();
    this.dataStorage.addAll(listObject);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: This is basically the same with refreshDataStorage(List<EntityObject> listObject)

Comment: No, because you use this.dataStorage = listObject that mean you change reference to listObject not dataStorage. notifyDataSetChanged() only work with dataStorage

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if(convertView == null){
        listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_images, parent, false);

        listViewHolder.downloadedImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.displayed_image);
        listViewHolder.deleteIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_image);
        listViewHolder.imageFilename = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.downloaded_filename);
        convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
    }else{
        listViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    listViewHolder.imageFilename.setText(dataStorage.get(position).getName());
    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Helper.PATH_TO_EXTERNAL_STORAGE + File.separator + dataStorage.get(position).getImage()));
    Glide.with(context).load(imageUri).override(90, 90).centerCrop().into(listViewHolder.downloadedImage);

    listViewHolder.deleteIcon.setTag(position);

    listViewHolder.deleteIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String deleteImageName = listViewHolder.imageFilename.getText().toString();
            String deletePath = Helper.PATH_TO_EXTERNAL_STORAGE + File.separator + deleteImageName;
            File deleteFile = new File(deletePath);
            if(deleteFile.exists()){
                deleteFile.delete();
                dataStorage.remove((Integer) v.getTag());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Your edited solution is perfect but @BNK solution came before yours and it works. Thanks for your help